# Javascript Click Event firing more than one time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have  used two div's to my page. For eg,

```
<div id="ListPage" data-role="content" style="background-color: gray; background-size: 100%;background-repeat: no-repeat; overflow: hidden;">
<div id="ListPageContent" style="width: 100%;"></div>                   
</div><div id='divViewMore' style='background-color:#D2D0C1;border-radius:5px;width:100%;height:20px;display:block;' align='center'><p style='text-align:center' >View more Here</p>
</div>
```

Here, listPageContent - I have added the data dynamically. When I'm clicking the divViewmore it's calling 2 times from my page. The follwing code I have used to my page.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#divViewMore").unbind().click(function() {
        alert('hello');
    });
});
```

If I'm using normal onclick event and also calling the handler, that time also I'm facing the same problem.

How should I avoid this problem? Please do the needful.

Comment: Try using event delegation

Comment: Are you sure that your code is loaded only once ? and also are you sure you do not call the same code two times ? I had the same problem in the past, but I discovered that I run the listener twice ... !

Comment: Nop.. it calls only one time... see [here](http://jsbin.com/iPeZEmo/1/edit)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/784JG/ ur code is working properly

Comment: #divViewMore search this on ur page and see how many time it come

Comment: The link you provide working correctly. It is run only once. Check again your code for double Js source load

Comment: It's works for me, even when I remove the unbind() that seems to be not nesessery.

Answer (score 0):

Handling click event requires only this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#divViewMore').click(function() {
        alert('Hello');
    });
});
```

Not sure why you should use `unbind()`

Answer (score 0):

This is the right way as i think::

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#divViewMore").unbind('click');
    $("#divViewMore").click(function() {
        alert('hello');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I created a fiddle from your code and there is no problem. Click event is not called twice.

```
$("#divViewMore").unbind().click(function () {
    alert('hello');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/TNZCU/

Not even if I add the click event multiple times. The unbind() seems to do its work.

```
var clickReceived = function () {
    alert('hello');
}
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {        
    $("#divViewMore").unbind().click(clickReceived);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/TNZCU/1/

If I remove the .Unbind(), alert is called multiple times.